# Mongodb aggregate (агрегация/группировка товаров)

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Решил поупражняться с парсерами и работой с mongodb, но столкнулся со следующей проблемой.

Имеется коллекция с товарами. Для примера возьмем следующие документы из нее:

```
{title: 'acer aspire 6420', source: 'amazon', price: 300}
{title: 'acer aspire 6420', source: 'ebay', price: 320}
```

Из них необходимо получить следующий документ:

```
{title: 'acer aspire 6420', amazon: 300, ebay: 320}
```

то есть сгруппировать по названию и вывести цену в каждом из магазинов.

В ходе разбирательства написал следующий код на питоне:

```
from bson.code import Code

reducer = Code("""
           function(origin, res){
                res[origin.source] = origin.price
           }
           """)

db.products.group(key={"source":1, 'title': 1, 'price': 1}, 
                  condition={'title': 'acer aspire 6420'}, 
                  initial={}, reduce=reducer)
```

но по итогу получаю вот такой результат:

```
{title: 'acer aspire 6420', source: 'amazon', price: 300, amazon: 300, ebay: 320}
{title: 'acer aspire 6420', source: 'ebay', price: 320, amazon: 300, ebay: 320}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону дальше копать или как это реализовать, чтобы результат получился таким:

```
{title: 'acer aspire 6420', amazon: 300, ebay: 320}
```

Я гуглил и читал документацию, правда.  Просто не очень понимаю как это все правильно связать вместе.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с aggregation framework (для mongoshell):

```
db.products.aggregate([
    {$match: {title: "acer aspire 6420"}},
    {$project: {_id: 0, title: 1, price: {source: "$source", value: "$price"} }},
    {$group: {_id: "$title", prices: {$push: "$price"}}}
])
```

Что дает на выходе:

```
{ "_id" : "acer aspire 6420", "prices" : [ { "source" : "amazon", "value" : 300 }, { "source" : "ebay", "value" : 320 } ] }
```

Первая операция фильтрует по названию (`title`) товара, следующая формирует поле `price` в виде объекта с двумя полями - `source` и `value`, и последняя операция группирует по `title`, добавляя все варианты цен в создаваемое поле-массив `prices`.

Т.к. у вас по условию задачи `source` должен быть именем поля в результате, а пока в `mongodb aggregation framework` поддержки динамических имен для создаваемых полей нет (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5947), то можно пройтись по результату с помощью `map`:

```
db.products.aggregate([
    {$match: {title: "acer aspire 6420"}},
    {$project: {_id: 0, title: 1, price: {source: "$source", value: "$price"} }},
    {$group: {_id: "$title", prices: {$push: "$price"}}}
]).map(function(e) {
    var r = {}
    r.title = e._id;
    e.prices.forEach(function(i){r[i.source] = i.value});
    return r;
})
```

Что даст на выходе:

```
[ { "title" : "acer aspire 6420", "amazon" : 300, "ebay" : 320 } ]
```

В этом случае есть вероятность (в отличии от первого варианта) потерять информацию, если у вас, например, для amazon есть две разных цены.

Для питона, думаю, сможете сделать по аналогии.

Comment: да, с переписыванием на питон проблем нет. спасибо большое, очень помогли

Comment: Если поля динамических, лущее решение это `mapReduce` если не можете изменить структуру документов. Но Я предлагаю вам изменить структуру документа, потому что `MapReduce` может вызвать падение производительности в вашем приложении